# Switch from branch to trunk as working copy in SVN (tortoise)

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I'm beginner. I created branch from trunk from xxx revision. In my new branch I've made e.x. 5 commits. I'd like to go back (switch) to xxx revision in trunk and I'd like to see my modificated files as changed in working copy in trunk (they should be in xxx revision and marked as changed - in red colour).

is it possible? How to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do a merge (minus the red color).  That's called merge and [TortoiseSVN provides documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html).  That said, I prefer to manually merge for small merge jobs.  I don't trust the automatic merge entirely.

To manually merge, you check out from the trunk, copy your five changes into that directory and then commit.